# Validation Message for enum list

Tags: .net, .net-core, data-annotations

I have an enum property in a view model as follows:

```
        [Display(Name = "Claim Type")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a claim type")]
        public ClaimType ClaimType { get; set; }
```

The ClaimType enum consists of values 1, 2, 3, and 4.
In the View I have the field as follows. Note the custom  default element:

```
  <select asp-for="ClaimType" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ClaimType>()">
    <option value="">Select Claim Type</option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="ClaimType" class="text-danger"></span>
```

When I leave the field empty and try to submit, the validation error message says:
The value '' is invalid.
The custom error message in the ViewModel is not being reached, because it seems it first validates if the value is a valid enum value.
Any idea how I can display a custom error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `Required` makes sense for non-nullable value types, so that you can try to use nullable `ClaimType` in your model like

```
[Display(Name = "Claim Type")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a claim type")] 
public ClaimType? ClaimType { get; set; }
```